# ASP.net web forms where to dispose of entity context using UnitOfWork pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dispose, unit-of-work

Throughout my web app I am using a UnitOfWork class to handle all my interactions with the data source. Below is the interface it inherits.

```
    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    ActivityService ActivityService { get; }
    AmendmentService AmendmentService { get; }
    AspUserService AspUserService { get; }
    AttachmentService AttachmentService { get; }
    CampaignService CampaignService { get; }
    CommentService CommentService { get; }
    EventRegistrationService EventRegistrationService { get; }
    GroupService GroupService { get; }
    InstanceService InstanceService { get; }


    void Commit();
}
```

It inherits Idisposable so i dispose the entity context during the UnitOfWorks Dispose method. However when using this class in my web pages i am never sure whether i should create one UnitOfWork class as a variable of the page like so.

```
public partial class Members_Request : BasePage
{
 UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork();

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Instance instance = uow.InstanceService.GetById(base.instanceId)
}


protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
//I don't think disposing here will work in all scenarios
uow.Dispose();
}

private void SomeOtherMethod(string name)
{ 
  Group newGroup = new Group{Name = name}

  uow.GroupService.Add(group))
  uow.Commit();
}
```

}

Doing it this way i need to be careful when i dispose for example, if i need the UnitOfWork in the Page_PreRender method but it never gets called becuase the request was a Callback, then my context will never get disposed. I am not sure if i should be disposing it during every method i use it then simply reinitialize it as a new UnitOfWork when i need it again to ensure it is always disposed.

An alternative way which ensures it gets dispose is to create a new UnitOfWork for every method i need it in so the above exmaple would become

```
  public partial class Members_Request : BasePage
{


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork();

  Instance instance = uow.InstanceService.GetById(base.instanceId)

  uow.Dispose();
}

private void SomeOtherMethod(string name)
{ 
  UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork();

  Group newGroup = new Group{Name = name}

  uow.GroupService.Add(group))
  uow.Commit();

  uow.Dispose();
}
```

}

So my question is how can i ensure that my UnitOfWork is always disposed when i share the same one each request, or should i just be creating many UnitOfWork objects whenever i need them and disposing them straight away. I think a solution by sharing the UnitOfWork would be better as it reducing code bloat.

**Edit** -- One alternative way i am thinking of doing this is to have this code in my base page

```
protected UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork();

    protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
    {
        uow.Dispose();
        base.OnUnload(e);
    }
```

Then i think i can just use the same instance of uow throughout the lifecycle and know it will always be disposed.

Comment: Do you use some kind of injection? Using Ninject or some other dependency injector usually gives you the possibility to define InRequestScope.

Comment: Inject your UoW and dispose it at the end of the request. Using DI and a container can help you with this. For example, http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ObjectLifestyleManagement#PerWebRequest

Comment: I agree you can use a DI framework to manage the object lifecycle for you. It would also mean if you hand off any processing to other service classes that require db access they can be injected with the same UOW instance to conserve resources and allow for caching etc etc

Answer (score 3):

I use this: override dispose in every page

```
public override void Dispose()
    {
        if(uow != null)
        {
            uow.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose();
    }
```

uow  is my UnitOfWork